# Best way to create list of parameters from string

Tags: bash, make

I have a variable with space separated list of paths. I need to send these paths to a program as a parameter like this `script.sh -i /dir1 -i /dir2`. What is the best way  to create such parameter list? Something like `$(echo "$paths" | sed 's|\([^[:space:]]\+\)|-i \1|g)` will work but it's unreadable given the fact that it's part of the makefile.

Comment: this question should be moved to [stackoverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list="one two three"
for i in $list; do params="$params -i $i"; done
script.sh $params
```

You will have troubles with paths with spaces, using `:` as paths separator is better

Answer (score 0):

use bash arrays

```
paths="/dir1 /dir2"
params=()
for path in $paths; do params+=( -i $path ); done
script.sh "${params[@]}"
```

Comment: You're correctly quoting the last expansion but none of the others; that will cause problems with spaces in filenames.
`for path in "$paths"; do params+=( -i "$path" ); done`

Comment: No. "I have a variable with space separated list of paths." Therefore, you must not quote `$paths` in the for statement, and you're guaranteed that `$path` will not have a space in it.

Comment: Ugh, you're right.
Brainfart on the silliness of the original question.